# How to centrally define and change a symbol that appears throughout an HTML/CSS document?

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML document containing some data, like this:

```
00000-00001
00020-00002
00000-00003
```

Currently, `-` is set to the delimiter, but, in the future, I may want to change this to another symbol, such as `|`, so the document displays like this:

```
00000|00001
00020|00002
00000|00003
```

I am accustomed to using TeX, where this is easily possible:

```
\def\delimiter{-}
00000\delimiter 00001
00020\delimiter 00002
00000\delimiter 00003
```

Is there any way within HTML or CSS2 to define a symbol, which then appears throughout a document, but then easily change this symbol wherever it appears?

Comment: If the delimiter isn't an essential part of the content you could make use of [generated content](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html) to insert the delimiter, via a class name and a `:before`/`:after` pseudo-element.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this with CSS2.

```
<div class="left">12345</div><div>67890</div>
<div class="left">67890</div><div>12345</div>
<div class="left">12345</div><div>67890</div>
<div class="left">67890</div><div>12345</div>
<div class="left">12345</div><div>67890</div>
```

The CSS is just enough to decorate the left `div` so that it stays to the left and puts a hyphen between it and the next div.

```
.left {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
.left:after {
    content: "-"
}
```

When you select the text, you will not get the delimiter. That is the only drawback I know of using this technique.

Check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/azuckerman/MqKAS/).

**UPDATE**

If you want the same thing with `span`s, this is the way I did it:

HTML

```
<span class="left">12345</span><span class="right">67890</span>
<span class="left">67890</span><span class="right">12345</span>
<span class="left">12345</span><span class="right">67890</span>
<span class="left">67890</span><span class="right">12345</span>
<span class="left">12345</span><span class="right">67890</span>
```

CSS

```
.left:after {
    content: "-";
}
.right:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
}
```

To get the right span to move to the next line, you have to have some content (in this case a space) or the display command gets ignored.

Comment: I suspect divs aren't the best element to use for wrapping each piece of data since they are blocks - if you change the divs to spans and wrap each pair in a paragraph, the data would be laid inline (including the `:after` pseudo-element) and you would not need to float anything.

Comment: Using `span`s required a class on the right column. You still have the separator not being included when you copy from your browser.

Comment: It really depends on how the content is originally laid out - taking the content from the question literally for instance, all the content would be flowing in a single line anyway. As for the highlighting issue - that's an inherent limitation with generated content. (This is why I specifically advise in my comment on the question to use GC only if the delimiter isn't essential.)

Answer (score 0):

No, people use preprocessing techniques or server-side technologies (such as PHP) for such purposes.

Theoretically, in HTML, you can define entities with `<!ENTITY ...>` declarations, but this has never been implemented, except in XHTML when served with an XML content type, which is not really feasible on the web. In CSS, there is nothing similar even at the theoretical level.